# Anonymous User Table Types as Parameter Types in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large number of stored-procedures planned for my project that all perform `MERGE` operations with user-supplied data which is passed into the stored procedure via `TABLE` parameters.

The syntax for such is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MergeFoo
    @values dbo.FooTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    MERGE dbo.Foo AS [target]
    USING @values AS [source] ON
        -- yada
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        -- yada

END
```

I understand this requires each table-type to be separately declared:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.FooTableType AS TABLE (
    Col1 int NOT NULL,
    Col2 nvarchar(50) NULL
)
```

This is a problem because each of these stored procedures takes an individualized table type, so each stored procedure is going to need its own table type - which hinders developer productivity (I note that you also cannot edit a table-type if a stored procedure is referencing it - you have to drop the stored procedure, edit the type, then re-create the stored procedure).

But if you have a table-valued variable you can declare the table-type anonymously, like so:

```
DECLARE @fooTable TABLE (
    Col1 int NOT NULL,
    Col2 nvarchar(50) NULL
)
```

Is it possible to have an anonymous table-type as a stored procedure parameter, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MergeFoo
    @values TABLE (
        Col1 int NOT NULL,
        Col2 nvarchar(50) NULL
    ) READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- yada
```

Of course, this syntax doesn't work and I get a syntax error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure MergeFoo, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

Comment: No, it's not possible, as you have already discovered by yourself. If many SPs looks like a good design to you (which is likely it is), then making many table types should be a consistent decision.

Comment: @IvanStarostin That is the answer.

Comment: If you're really concerned about productivity, you could extend a database project in Visual Studio to generate the table types (for example through T4 templates) in sync with your tables. That said, I'm not sure if a DACPAC can correctly figure out the deployment order for a changed table type. Conceivably you could do this with a live database using DDL triggers, but I definitely don't recommend this approach -- the T-SQL needed is quite hairy. Another alternative, of course, is to drop the procedures and use a statement generator.